# Unknown class '_FITagEditorView' error : is this normal?

Tags: cocoa, tags, osx-mavericks, nspersistentdocument

I am using the `NSPersistentDocument` class. 
When opening a document, I have the following error.

```
Unknown class '_FITagEditorView', using 'NSView' instead. 
Encountered in Interface Builder file at path /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Resources/French.lproj/NSNavPanelContentView.nib.
```

Did anyone of you have the same error?
Is it normal (it is caused by the new features of `Mavericks`)?
How can I solve it?

Comment: Got the same error. This came with Mavericks, probably a bug.

Answer (score 2):

`FITagEditorView` is a private class in Mavericks that is presumably responsible for allowing the user to search for / assign tags on `NSOpenPanel` and `NSSavePanel` respectively.

In AppKit, `NSSavePanel` has a private instance variable of type `NSSavePanelAuxiliary`, which contains a pointer to an instance of `FITagEditorView`. `NSOpenPanel` is a subclass of `NSSavePanel` is it has this pointer, as well.

`FITagEditorView` is defined in a private `FinderKit.framework`, which is in /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks.

I’m not sure why your app isn’t automatically linking it in when needed, although honestly I can’t find what frameworks pull it in—it might be something only pulled in by the PowerBox. Are you running Sandboxed? Is there something odd about your linking step?

Comment: I thought maybe it is because I changed the `.xib` of `Menu.xib` (to improve the support of French language). That's an intuition. Do you think it can make any sense?

Comment: You changed the name of the file or you changed something in it? Do you mean your project’s “MainMenu.xib” or some other “Menu.xib”?

Comment: It was changes in `/Contents/Developer/Library/Xcode/Templates/Project Templates/Mac/Application/Cocoa Document-based Application.xctemplate/Document.xib` and `/Contents/Developer/Library/Xcode/Templates/Project Templates/Mac/Application/Cocoa Document-based Application.xctemplate/MainMenuDoc.xib`(under `Xcode 4`) when I created my project. Theses `.xib` files are now the default ones. I don't know if it can have an impact.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help... I am not running sandboxed. The architecture is the default one.

Answer (score 1):

I get it in Mavericks just calling "NSOpenPanel* openDlg = [NSOpenPanel openPanel]" in French but in none of our other 18 languages.